# upnp, c++ and boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, upnp

I use miniupnpc with my wrapper. When my friend run my app, the app create upnp.

[image]
But, he still do not receive messages from my computer. What I do wrong ?

Source client:

```
upnp::upnp_wrapper upnp{};
upnp.redirect(upnp::internal_port{ 41052 }, 
              upnp::external_port{ 41052 }, 
              upnp::eProtocol::UDP, "Description");

io_service service;
ip::udp::socket socket{ service };
socket.open(ip::udp::v4());
socket.bind(ip::udp::endpoint{ ip::udp::v4(), 41052 });

ip::udp::endpoint server_ep{ ip::address::from_string("100.71.188.14"s), 9999u };

std::cout << "open: " << socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() << ':' << socket.local_endpoint().port() << '\n';



cout << "send request\n";
socket.send_to(buffer("open: " + socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() + ':' + std::to_string(socket.local_endpoint().port()) + '\n'), server_ep);
cout << "request sent\n\n";

array<char, 60> buff = {};
cout << "wait answer\n";
auto answer_length = socket.receive(buffer(buff));
cout << "answer recived: ";
cout.write(buff.data(), answer_length);

cout << "\nsend goodd\n";
socket.send_to(buffer("GOOOOD"s), server_ep);


cout << "\n\nEND";
cin.get();
```

and server test source:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace literals;
using namespace boost::asio;

io_service service;
ip::udp::socket socket{ service };
socket.open(ip::udp::v4());
socket.bind(ip::udp::endpoint{ ip::udp::v4(), 9999u });
ip::udp::endpoint client_ep;

array<char, 100> buff = {};
cout << "start recive\n";
auto recived_length = socket.receive_from(buffer(buff), client_ep);
cout << "message recived from: " + client_ep.address().to_string() + ':' + to_string(client_ep.port()) + "\n-> ";
std::cout.write(buff.data(), recived_length);

cout << "\n\nsend answer\n";
socket.send_to(buffer("ANSWER"s), client_ep);
cout << "answer sent\n";

cout << "start good\n";
 recived_length = socket.receive_from(buffer(buff), client_ep);
std::cout.write(buff.data(), recived_length);

cout << "\nEND";
cin.get();
```

What I do wrong with upnp and boost asio? how correctly using upnp opened internal and external port?

Comment: Does your server work locally, i.e. without upnp in between?

Comment: no, i've forwarded port in my router for my pc. I can get msg from client, but clent can'g hear answers

Comment: but router open another port. Not witch i open when opening socket.